# Writing a TableRow on UI thread with data from AsyncTask Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have implemented a JSON Parser on a background thread and then am trying to write the data to a series of TableRows on the UI Thread using some embedded code which includes a handler to put me back on the normal UI Thread. The code continually comes back with this stack trace

```
Process: webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3, PID: 6123
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:402)
        at     webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3.MainActivity$ProgressTask$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:244)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 14:58:08.506    6199-6199/webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3 D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-21 14:58:11.316    6199-6215/webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 209K, 10% free 3129K/3460K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
04-21 14:58:11.336    6199-6199/webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-21 14:58:11.336    6199-6199/webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0cb3b20)
04-21 14:58:11.336    6199-6199/webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3, PID: 6199
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:402)
        at webmd.mmu.ac.uk.wmfinal3.MainActivity$ProgressTask$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:245)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried moving all the code into the AsyncTask but it then demands to be on the UI Thread.

Here is my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
 final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
final TableRow v1  = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String temp = "http://sandbox.kriswelsh.com/hygieneapi/hygiene.php?op=nearest&lat=" + latitude + "&long=" + longitude;
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(temp);
int [] test = new int [10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String vid = c.getString(id);
                String vbn = c.getString(BusinessName);
                String va1 = c.getString(Add1);
                String va2 = c.getString(Add2);
                String va3 = c.getString(Add3);
                String vpost = c.getString(Post);
                String vlong = c.getString(longitudej);
                String vrate = c.getString(RatingDate);
                String vratestar = c.getString(Rating);
                String vlat = c.getString(latitudej);

                if (vratestar.contentEquals("-1")) {
                    vratestar = "Exempt";
                }




                //testing(vbn,va1,va2,va3,vpost,vratestar);
                //TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);


                isRunning = true;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while (isRunning) {
                            try {
                                // Thread.sleep(10000);
                                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        tl.addView(v1);


                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
                isRunning = false;

                //jsonlist.add(map);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            return null;
        }
```

UPDATE: Now shows v1 initialization

Comment: you shouldnt be updating the ui in doInBackground. you should be returning it, and override on post execute which should handle all ui logic there

Comment: please show `v1` initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your `while (isRunning)` loop I suppose you are trying to add the same `v1` `TableRow` view to the `TableLayout` on each iteration (however, it is just a guess, because you didn't post `v1` declaration). Of course, at the second time it will give you an error as it is already has parent, you should create new `TableRow` object each time. Going deeper, you don't need `Handler` which is connected to `UI` thread, because you are using `AsyncTask`, you can take advantage of the fact, that `onPostExecute` method is executed on the main thread. Considering it, you can write the following `AsyncTask` implementation:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>{

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String temp = "http://sandbox.kriswelsh.com/hygieneapi/hygiene.php?op=nearest&lat=" + latitude + "&long=" + longitude;
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(temp);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String vid = c.getString(id);
                String vbn = c.getString(BusinessName);
                String va1 = c.getString(Add1);
                String va2 = c.getString(Add2);
                String va3 = c.getString(Add3);
                String vpost = c.getString(Post);
                String vlong = c.getString(longitudej);
                String vrate = c.getString(RatingDate);
                String vratestar = c.getString(Rating);
                String vlat = c.getString(latitudej);

                if (vratestar.contentEquals("-1")) {
                    vratestar = "Exempt";
                }

                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
                //configuring row, setting layout params
                tl.addView(tableRow);

            } catch (JSONException ex){
                //error handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```